# Outlook 2010 compatibility with Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have recently installed Outlook 2013 as part of the Office 2013 package. I loaded my old 2010 outlook.pst file with all my emails to the Outlook directory it but cannot get Outlook 2013 to read any of the emails in it. Outlook 2013 does recognize the file since it is one of the folders listed in Outlook 2013.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: close outlook, run scanpst.exe and scan your pst file. try again.